# Add controller to the end of SwaggerDoc

Tags: c#, swagger

Swagger automatically sorts controllers alphabetically, but I want to add one controller to the end of the documentation without changing it's name. How can I do that?

Comment: May be this could [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59845491/10048934)

Comment: Move your endpoint to a different Class and swagger will automatically create different accordion for it. you can collapse and expand others easily then.